# A generalized Ahmed's integral

Tags: integration, special-functions

Let $\vec{A}:=(A_1,A_2,A_3)$ be a vector where all its components are positive real numbers.
In the context of this question [An integral involving error functions and a Gaussian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2358738/an-integral-involving-error-functions-and-a-gaussian/2362639#2362639) we came across  a following integral.
\begin{equation}
I(\vec{A}) := A_1\int\limits_0^{A_3} \frac{ \arctan\left(\frac{A_2}{\sqrt{1+A_1^2 +\xi^2}}\right)}{(1+\xi^2)\sqrt{1+A_1^2+\xi^2}} d\xi
\end{equation}
By performing the following transformations, firstly by substituting $\xi = \sqrt{1+A_1^2} \tan(\theta)$and then by substituting $t=\tan(\theta/2)$ we brought the quantity being sought for  to the following form:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&I(\vec{A}) = \arctan(\frac{A_1 A_3}{\sqrt{1+A_1^2+A_3^2}}) \arctan(\frac{A_2}{\sqrt{1+A_1^2+A_3^2}})+\\
&&4 A_2\sqrt{1+A_1^2}\int\limits_0^{B} \arctan(\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+A_1^2}-A_1}) \cdot \frac{ t}{A_2^2 (1-t^2)^2 + (1+A_1^2) (1+t^2)^2} dt-\\
&&4 A_2\sqrt{1+A_1^2}\int\limits_0^{B} \arctan(\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+A_1^2}+A_1}) \cdot \frac{ t}{A_2^2 (1-t^2)^2 + (1+A_1^2) (1+t^2)^2} dt
\end{eqnarray}
where $B:= (-\sqrt{1+A_1^2} + \sqrt{1+A_1^2+A_3^2})/A_3$.

Now the question is how do we complete the calculation? Is the result expressed through elementary functions only and if not what kind of special functions enter the result?

Answer (score 2):

Define $\phi:= \arccos(A_2/\sqrt{1+A_1^2+A_2^2})$ and $\alpha := \sqrt{1+A_1^2}-A_1$ and $\beta:=\sqrt{1+A_1^2}+A_1$ and
\begin{eqnarray}
&&{\mathcal F}^{(a,b)}(t):=\int \arctan(\frac{t}{a}) \frac{1}{t-b} dt = \log(t-b) \arctan(\frac{t}{a})\\
&&-\frac{1}{2 \imath} \left( \log(t-b) \left[ \log(\frac{t-\imath a}{b-\imath a}) - \log(\frac{t+\imath a}{b+\imath a})\right] + Li_2(\frac{b-t}{b-\imath a}) -  Li_2(\frac{b-t}{b+\imath a})\right)
\end{eqnarray}

By using the following partial fraction decomposition :
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{t}{A_2^2(1-t^2)^2 + (1+A_1^2) (1+t^2)^2} = 
\frac{I}{8 A_2 \sqrt{1+A_1^2}} \left( -\frac{1}{t-e^{\imath\phi}} + \frac{1}{t-e^{-\imath\phi}}+\frac{1}{t+e^{-\imath\phi}}-\frac{1}{t+e^{\imath\phi}}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
and by integrating each fraction over $t$ using the antiderivative above we arrive at the following result:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&I(\vec{A})= \arctan\left( \frac{A_1 A_3}{\sqrt{1+A_1^2+A_3^2}}\right) + \arctan\left( \frac{A_2}{\sqrt{1+A_1^2+A_3^2}}\right)+\\
&&\left.\frac{\imath}{2} \left(
{\mathcal F}^{\alpha,+\exp(-\imath \phi))}(t) +
{\mathcal F}^{\alpha,-\exp(-\imath \phi))}(t) -
{\mathcal F}^{\alpha,-\exp(+\imath \phi))}(t) -
{\mathcal F}^{\alpha,+\exp(+\imath \phi))}(t) 
\right)\right|_0^B -\\
&&\left.\frac{\imath}{2} \left(
{\mathcal F}^{\beta,+\exp(-\imath \phi))}(t) +
{\mathcal F}^{\beta,-\exp(-\imath \phi))}(t) -
{\mathcal F}^{\beta,-\exp(+\imath \phi))}(t) -
{\mathcal F}^{\beta,+\exp(+\imath \phi))}(t) 
\right)\right|_0^B
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: (+1) What is $\mathcal F$?